# instant search jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, plugins

First of all this is how the script works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/7Rm8U/7/light/)

The 'searchList' setting specifies the content that will be searched. In this case it is searchable tr. Finally, the 'searchItem' setting allows to dive in and specify an individual element to search. In this case, I use 'td'.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTdwU/8/)

I have a list of thumbnail images with some informations, what I want to do is to be able to search for "something" and then to show the image and the text related to that specific thumbnail. 
Hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've tried to target a lot  elements in the plugin but with no succes, I think I'm missing something...

Comment: The code in the fiddles is very hard to go through. It would be better if you could post some of the relevant code here, and describe where you are stuck. When you edit the question, also make sure to add the `Javascript` tag

Comment: I'm stuck at defining the search items for the plugin, if you take a look at the first fiddle you will see that with that markup is working proper, but on 2nd fiddle is not working...

Comment: I've made the markup more clean please check again my fiddle

Comment: What's the question? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out on a limb, but your selector for `searchList` looks wrong:

```
'searchList' : '.imgscontainer portfolio-v6-items ',
```

Surely that second class should have a dot before it, and they're on the same element, so no space:

```
 class="imgscontainer portfolio-v6-items"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand,  do you mean to put in the 'searchList'  .imgscontainer portfolio-v6-items without space between them ?